# How to get java substring ignoring \r\n and few html tags

Tags: java

Original String

```
\r\n HDFC Bank <\/a>\r\n <\/div>\r\n <\/td>\r\n
```

Required sub-string

```
HDFC Bank
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) library to parse HTML content, and extract content text from it.

With JSoup, you parse an input content to a "Document" structure that contains HTML "Elements". On each Jsoup "Element" or "Document", you will find a [text()](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text()) method that allow to extract and trim text content from parsed HTML elements:

> Gets the normalized, combined text of this element and all its children. Whitespace is normalized and trimmed.
>
> [...]
>
> Note that this method returns the textual content that would be presented to a reader.

Example:

```java
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

public class JsoupGetText {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var txt = "\r\n HDFC Bank </a>\r\n </div>\r\n </td>\r\n";

        var extracted = Jsoup.parse(txt).text();
        System.out.println('\''+extracted+'\'');
    }
}
```

prints:

```
'HDFC Bank'
```

Comment: As HTML presents white space (multiple spaces and line breaks) as one space HTML parsing is indeed a nice versatile solution.

Comment: This is not working for me,  extracted is returning same value back instead of parsed one.

Comment: I've wrongly assumed that the bunch of extra \ in your text have been added when you've formatted it in the question. If they indeed are in the original text, then your input html is corrupted. You might use regex to work around the problem, though. Something like that : `txt.replaceAll("(\\r\\n)|(<\\?/?\w+/?>)").trim();`

Comment: @vikramvi : My example replaceAll above is wrong (wrote it on the fly on my phone, bad idea). The fixed one would be : `txt.replaceAll("(\\\\r\\\\n)|(<\\\\?/?\\w+/?>)", "").trim()`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time, it worked. I was wondering what was I doing wrong with JSOUP earlier. RegEx is the ultimate solution for all the problems :)